Laravel Livewire pagination currentPage()
I have a problem using the pagination from Laravel Livewire. I use the bootstrap view from livewire and it's working fine.
In other projects i used something like this (without Livewire) to set the robots nofollow/follow attribute:
@if($listings->currentPage() == 1)
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    @else
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
    @endif

But in livewire i don't have the opportunity to use currentPage()
I tried to use somehting like this in my livewire controller:
$robots = $this->currentPage() == 1 ? 'index, follow' : 'noindex, follow';
And then use the
@section('robots')
    <meta name="robots" content="{{ $robots }}">
@endsection

But sill getting the error: Method App\Livewire\ProviderListingFilter::currentPage does not exist.
Is there any simple solution to do that? I can't find anything in the docs.

Inertia apps are rendered within the document , they are unable to render markup to the document , as it's outside of their scope. Use Head component instead.

If you check the upgrade docs regarding pagination, you can see they now support multiple paginators. This is expanded further.
While I don't exactly know what $listings is in this case, I wouldn't suggest using the LengthAwarePaginator::currentPage method, but instead Livewire's own getPage method.
